# Making a Function to Count Elements In Multiple Arrays

Tags: c#

Hullo,

For some reason (that I can't work out) a function that returns an ilist keeps returning null when I call it (even though earlier in the same method it returns an empty ilist, but whatever) so I was making a function to take in several ilists and then output the total number of elements across all the lists (ignoring the null ones as to avoid an exception).

So far I have:

```
private int TotalItemsInLists(params IList[] lists)
    {
        int total = 0;


        foreach (IList list in lists)
            if (list != null)
                total += list.Count;

        return total;
    }
```

but that causes problems in that `params IList[] lists` doesn't seem to be called correctly, as the ILists are all lists of different types.

Anyone know how I can remedy this problem?

Thanks,
Harry

Edit: Here is the code that calls it

```
private bool TooManyItems(Person person)
    {
        return TotalItemsInLists(jobService.BeingDevelopedBy(person), jobService.BeingTestedBy(person),
                                 jobService.BeingFixedBy(person), quoteService.BeingProducedBy(person),
                                 ticketService.BeingActivelyHandledBy(person),
                                 ticketService.BeingTestedBy(person),
                                 ticketService.AllAvailable(person)) > 10;
    }
```

And here's an example of one of the methods they call (they're all pretty similar, just different databases and filters)

```
public IList<Ticket> BeingActivelyHandledBy(Person person)
    {
        return (from ticket in Query()
                where ticket.Handler == person
                      && ticket.Status == TicketStatus.Open
                      && ticket.Release == null
                select ticket).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the call to your method

Comment: Can you provide a code example and the exptected result?

Comment: Lists that you're passing as parameters are declared as generic? I mean List<User> userList = new List<User>();?

Comment: There's the code to explain it better, sorry

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be called correctly" mean?

Comment: Red wiggly line under my parameters in the call to the method saying `Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.Ilist<ProjectSupport.Core.Domain.Job>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Collections.IList'`

Comment: The problem is that your methods return IList<T> instead of List<T>. See my answer on how to fix this in a proper manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast the input to `IList`:

```
TotalItemsInLists((IList)jobService.BeingDevelopedBy(person), ...
```

Comment: There isn't any guarantee that the lists will even implement the non-generic IList. IList<T> guarantees ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable, and that's it.

Comment: true, I think Øyvind's proposal to return List<T> instead of IList<T> is the best answer

Comment: That doesn't address the problem at all, which is that the method is being given multiple instances of IList<T> where T is different, thus the solution is to cast them down to a non-generic interface, the only one of which that is guaranteed to work is IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

If your `IList<T>`s are all objects that implement `ICollection` (which is likely, as most of the collection classes in the BCL that implement `IList<T>` also implement `ICollection`), then you can simply cast to `ICollection`, although you will lose type-safety.

```
private int TotalItemsInLists(params object[] lists)
{
    int total = 0;

    // this casts each object implicitly to ICollection
    foreach (ICollection list in lists)
        if (list != null)
            total += list.Count;

    return total;
}
```

If not, then you need to go back to the non-generic `IEnumerable` and use `Cast<object>`:

```
private int TotalItemsInLists(params IEnumerable[] lists)
{
    int total = 0;

    foreach (IEnumerable list in lists)
        if (list != null)
            total += list.Cast<object>().Count();

    return total;
}
```

Comment: missing '()' after Cast<object> should be list.Cast<object>().Count();

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing you can do is change the method to accept the non-generic `IEnumerable` type.

```
private int TotalItemsInLists(params IEnumerable[] lists)
{
    int total = 0;

    foreach (var list in lists)
        if (list != null)
            total += list.Count();

    return total;
}
```

If performance becomes a problem, you can do a quick check in the loop if the type is also a generic or non-generic ICollection and read its Count property directly.

Comment: Why doing if (list != null)? list.Count() is an extension method and doesn't need this extra if.

Comment: If `source` is null, `Count()` throws an ArgumentNullException

Comment: Even though it isn't a requirement for extension methods, all the Linq extension methods throw ArgumentNullExceptions regardless. Count() is no exception (pardon the pun).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your list generation methods return for example `List<Ticket>` instead of `IList<Ticket>` it should work out just fine, since `List<T>` implements `IList`.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, the reason your code doesn't work is because the generic [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) does *not* implement the non-generic [`IList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) interface (it's only coincidental that `List<T>` happens to implement both interfaces.).

It appears that the *static* types of the arguments you are passing are all `IList<SomeThing>`, so what you have clearly isn't going to work.

One workaround would be to just rely on the classic `IEnumerable` interface and do all the leg-work in the method itself, i.e. figure out the fastest way to get each sub-sequence's count.

Here's an untested sample:

```
private static int TotalItemsInLists(params IEnumerable[] lists)
{
    if(lists == null)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("lists");

    return lists.Sum(l => l == null ? 0 : GetCount(l));      
}

private static int GetCount(IEnumerable source)
{
    var collection = source as ICollection;
    if (collection != null)
        return collection.Count;

    var genCollType = source.GetType().GetInterfaces()
                      .FirstOrDefault
                      (i => i.IsGenericType 
                       && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>));

    if (genCollType != null)
        return (int)genCollType.GetProperty("Count").GetValue(source, null);

    return source.Cast<object>().Count();
}
```

Comment: Why do not do return lists.Sum(x=>x.Count()) in your first function?

Comment: @Saeed: That wouldn't work; `Count` is defined for `IEnumerable<T>`. Remember, we are talking about sequences of different types here. It is a bit of a pity there's no `Count()` extension for `IEnumerable` though.